# "Tabela" apenas para consultas - Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic3, realtime-database

Estou desenvolvendo um app com `firebase` (*RealTime*) e `ionic3`.
Não tenho muito conhecimento nessa tecnologia, e não consegui esclarecer uma dúvida com minhas pesquisas:

> É possível criar uma tabela apenas para consulta ?
>   ***Por exemplo***, preciso de uma tabela para APENAS trazer produtos para pesquisa, isso é possível ?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se compreendi bem sua dúvida, porém, como descrito na documentação:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart?hl=pt-br

> As regras do banco de dados exigem o Firebase Authentication e
>   concedem permissões de leitura e gravação somente a usuários
>   autenticados. As regras padrão garantem que o banco de dados não seja
>   acessado por ninguém antes de ser configurado. Depois, personalize-as
>   de acordo com suas necessidades. Confira alguns exemplos comuns:

```
// These rules don't allow anyone read or write access to your database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Portanto, definindo essas regras, é possível configurar o nível de acesso de cada usuário aos dados, nesse mesmo [link da documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart?hl=pt-br), existe uma explicação mais profunda sobre definição destas regras para usuários.